# else statement content wont show?

Tags: php, html, client-side

Currently, my problem continues to persist as I want to display errors for existing accounts or a success message if the user creates a non-already existing account. For some odd reason, even if the sign-up is successful, it still display the errors? Is there something that I am doing wrong? The two if statements still run even if they are false??? I am not understanding...

```
if ($db_found) {

    $uSQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username'";
    $uresult = mysql_query($uSQL);
    $unum_rows = mysql_num_rows($uresult);

    $eSQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '$email'";
    $eresult = mysql_query($eSQL);
    $enum_rows = mysql_num_rows($eresult);

    if ($unum_rows > 0) {
        echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Username Already Exists</li></div>';
    }
    if ($enum_rows > 0) {
        echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Email Already Exists</li></div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="success-message">successfully</div>';
    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest thay you will give your variable a descriptive name.

Comment: Have you tried printing out your actual query and running them in phpmyadmin to make sure they work and return the proper results that you expect.

Comment: You can get a success and an error with the logic you currently have, say $unum_rows > 0 && $enum_rows == 0, you will get error for name and success for email.

Comment: You aren't adding the new account before this check by chance are you? You don't actually have that code posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would combine the queries - and simplify the logic ( and escape your input )

```
if ($db_found) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '{mysql_real_escape_string($username)}' OR email = '{mysql_real_escape_string($email)}'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if( mysql_num_rows($result) ){
       while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
          if($row['username'] == $username ){
               echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Username Already Exists</li></div>';
          }
          if($row['email'] == $email) {
               echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Email Already Exists</li></div>';
          }
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="success-message">successfully</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I did a little more research and incorporated this bit of code and it finally works!

Comment: Sure glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
$enum_rows = mysql_num_rows($eresult);
if($unum_rows < 1)
{
 echo "Username is available";
}
else
{
 echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Username Already Exists</li></div>';
}
if($enum_rows < 1)
{
 echo '<div class="success-message">successfully</div>';
}
else
{
  echo '<div class="error-message"><li>Email Already Exists</li></div>';
}
```